# not able to add new key value pair in the JSON object kindly some one help me out

Tags: javascript, java, json, object, lwc

I am trying to add key value pair in the below JSON object, but it is getting added in the wrong way, is there any way i can add to each object a new  key value pair, that will help me to complete the req.

JSON as follow :

```
var object =[
      {
         "asdf":"",
         "fdrtf":"869966",
         "hdhfhfh":"utytut",
         "Cat":"A"
         
      },
      {
         "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B"
         
      },
      {
         "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B"
      }
]

code i am using to add the new key value pair :
for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
            object[i]['ABC'] = [i];
        }
```

Actually expected should be:

```
var object =[
      {
         "asdf":"",
         "fdrtf":"869966",
         "hdhfhfh":"utytut",
         "Cat":"A",
         "ABC": "0"
         
      },
      {
         "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B",
         "ABC": "1"
         
      },
      {
         "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B"
         "ABC": "2"
      }
]
```

the final value i am getting as below:

```
["0":{
         "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B",
      
   },
   "1":{
         "asdf":"",
         "fdrtf":"869966",
         "hdhfhfh":"utytut",
         "Cat":"A"
         
   },
   "2":{
       "hjhj":"",
         "hfhfhf":"h",
         "hhfh":"hfjfhdj",
         "cat":"B"
   }
  ]
```

kindly someone help me out to get the expected value,,,really need it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code which you have pasted looks ok. but you are assigning the array to `ABC` property.

Remove the array and just assign the value.

```
for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
        object[i]['ABC'] = i
}
```

**working example:**

```js
var object = [
    {
        "asdf": "",
        "fdrtf": "869966",
        "hdhfhfh": "utytut",
        "Cat": "A"

    },
    {
        "hjhj": "",
        "hfhfhf": "h",
        "hhfh": "hfjfhdj",
        "cat": "B"

    },
    {
        "hjhj": "",
        "hfhfhf": "h",
        "hhfh": "hfjfhdj",
        "cat": "B"
    }
]

for (let i = 0; i < object.length; i++) {
    object[i]['ABC'] = i
}

console.log(object);

//Use JSON.stringify if you need Json string
console.log(JSON.stringify(object));
```

**Using ES6 `map` and spread operator**

```js
var object = [
    {
        "asdf": "",
        "fdrtf": "869966",
        "hdhfhfh": "utytut",
        "Cat": "A"

    },
    {
        "hjhj": "",
        "hfhfhf": "h",
        "hhfh": "hfjfhdj",
        "cat": "B"

    },
    {
        "hjhj": "",
        "hfhfhf": "h",
        "hhfh": "hfjfhdj",
        "cat": "B"
    }
]

let updatedObject = object.map( (item, index) => ({...item, 'ABC': index}));
console.log(updatedObject);

//Use JSON.stringify if you need Json string
console.log(JSON.stringify(updatedObject));
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(object) if you want to pass it as body of the request.

Comment: @sohail Ashraf i am getting something like that :

Comment: [Object { asdf: "", fdrtf: "869966", hdhfhfh: "utytut", Cat: "A", ABC: 0 }, Object { hjhj: "", hfhfhf: "h", hhfh: "hfjfhdj", cat: "B", ABC: 1 }, Object { hjhj: "", hfhfhf: "h", hhfh: "hfjfhdj", cat: "B", ABC: 2 }]

Comment: May I know what are you using to convert the object to JSON ?

Comment: let object = Object.assign({}, data);  it is just a responce coming from parent to child

Comment: then you just need to use JSON.parse(data), to parse the JSON string